# Does x264 support multicore encoding on ARM?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, video-encoding, x264

I'm trying to get x264 encoder to use multiple CPU cores.
I'm changing i_threads value in the x264_param_t structure. I've tried to set it to different values from 1 to 6 and I don't see any change in performance.

I'm using https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264 project with these flags:
./configure --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- --enable-pic --host=arm-linux

Is multithreaded encoding supported on ARM? Will it give me significant boost in performance on a 4 core CPU?

Comment: I think it depends on your devices. if your device have 4-core, it should be boosted.

Comment: It will always depend on the command line.  If you have a filter chain that is not parallel friendly, then it probably will not.  Most people don't take `src == dst` for resolution, bit depth, no filtering, not telecine, no audio, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out threading support was not enabled in my x264 Android build.
By default x264 configure script doesn't find pthreads library, because Android NDK doesn't include it as a standalone library.
As a workaround I've created an empty libpthreads.a to enable POSIX threads support in my build.